# Nextflow: How to define a environment var in process A and call this env var in process B?

Tags: bash, groovy, nextflow, nextflow-tower

I am new to the Nextflow. I want to define a environment a in the process A:

```
process define_env {
output:
env var_a
"""
echo var_a="test" > var_file.txt
source var_file.txt
"""
}
```

And then I want to call environment `var_a` in the following process:

```
process call_var {
"""
echo This is a $var_a.
"""
}

//And run two processes
workflow {
define_env()
call_var()
}
```

It reports the error: `No such variable: var_a`. Could you please help me to figure out how to fix it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every processing environment is different, so to my knowledge environmental variables will need to be defined for each process you use.

If you're creating the file `var_file.txt`, you can output the file using `path(var_file.txt)` in the output declaration. In the process `call_var`, you can then use  `path(var_file.txt)` in the input declaration but would need to amend your workflow declaration so that `call_var` takes the output of the first process.

```
process define_env {
  output:
  path(var_file.txt), emit: vars

  script:
  """
  echo var_a="test" > var_file.txt
  source var_file.txt
  """
}

process call_var {
  input:
  path(var_file)

  script:
  """
  source ${var_file}
  echo This is a $var_a.
  """
}

//And run two processes
workflow {
  define_env()
  call_var(define_env.out.vars)
}
```

An alternative if you are using the same env variable in all processes would be to define it in the config file and export it as an environmental variable in each process (i.e., `export ${params.global_variable}=test` in each process. You can even use the `beforeScript` [directive](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#beforescript) to ensure it's read into the environment in each process.